# Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create at com.google.maps.api

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps on my android application. on Some devices **Galaxy S5**, **J5** and **S5 LTE-A** I am getting "`Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again`" error. I got the following log from the Fabric Crashlytics, I was not able to reproduce this issue,

Here is the log I got,

```
       Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.s.t(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518438:317)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.s.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518438:256)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.l.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518438:109)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.n.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518438:37)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This solved my issue,

1. Added `android:largeHeap="true"` on my AndroidManifest.xml
2. changed `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m` to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` on gradle.properties
3. Added on my applications build.gradle file

   `android {
       dexOptions {
           incremental true
           javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
       }
   }`

Comment: Are not those options for `Gradle` process which is building apk? How could that solve the `OutOfMemoryError` crash of the application, as those gradle memory options do not relate to the memory of the process which runs the apk on the device?

Comment: I have the same issue, Is it really work? Can someone explain why we using this approach?

Comment: Only `android:largeHeap="true"` affects application runtime. 2. and 3. affects application build performance. It's not an correct answer.

Comment: How this is going to fix the crash?

Answer (score -2):

When running 32 bit java there is a limit to how much memory can be used. I don't know if it can be changed but the easy solution is using a 64 bit build of java.